# Python pandas: split and append?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, ipython

I have a table 'a' like this:

```
    count  cc
    68  IL-US
    1   IL
    12  US
    5   US
    1180    US-DE
    4424    GB-ES-DE-A1-FR
    0   
    20  DE
    37  A1
```

I want to have the sum of counts for each country, like this:

```
    count   cc
    1265    US
    69      IL
    4424    GB
    4424    ES  
    4424    FR  
    5624    DE
    4461    A1
```

I have tried this , but this does not splits , this only groups them and sum the counts:

```
a.head(50).groupby(['cc']).aggregate(sum)['count']
```

Does anybody know how can I do that in ipython pandas?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to apply a function to your df to split the 'cc' column and create a new dict that contains each split country and their associated count, you can then construct a new df from this, groupby the country and perform the sum on the count:

```
In [72]:

from collections import defaultdict
master = defaultdict(list)
def func(x):
    if pd.isnull(x['cc']):
        return
    t = defaultdict(list)
    for v in x['cc'].split('-'):
        master['country'].append(v) 
        master['count'].append(x['count'])

df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(master))
df
Out[72]:
    count country
0      68      IL
1      68      US
2       1      IL
3      12      US
4       5      US
5    1180      US
6    1180      DE
7    4424      GB
8    4424      ES
9    4424      DE
10   4424      A1
11   4424      FR
12     20      DE
13     37      A1
In [73]:

df.groupby('country')['count'].sum()
Out[73]:
country
A1    4461
DE    5624
ES    4424
FR    4424
GB    4424
IL      69
US    1265
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

If you want the Country identifier back as a column you can call `reset_index`:

```
In [74]:

df.groupby('country')['count'].sum().reset_index()
Out[74]:
  country  count
0      A1   4461
1      DE   5624
2      ES   4424
3      FR   4424
4      GB   4424
5      IL     69
6      US   1265
```